# ¿Como acceder a un control que tiene index 0?

Tags: vb6, textbox

Tengo este problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Justo en esa línea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese error ocurre con la terminación de `txtAddPrefijo.Text`. Ese `.Text` no existe. Lo que sucede, es que en las propiedades de ese TextBox y de los demás el índice está en 0.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque por medio de un botón, yo presionándolo, añado más campos. Por lo que lo voy haciendo mediante un índice:

```
Dim indice As Integer
Private Sub btnAñadir_Click()
   indice = indice + 1
   Load uc1(indice)
   Set uc1(indice).Container = Picture1
   uc1(indice).Visible = True
   uc1(indice).Top = IIf(indice = 1, 0, uc1(indice - 1).Top + uc1(indice - 1).Height + 20)
   Load txtAddPrefijo(indice)
   Set txtAddPrefijo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   txtAddPrefijo(indice).Visible = True
   txtAddPrefijo(indice).Top = txtAddPrefijo(indice - 1).Top
End Sub
```

La cuestión es que, necesito guardar el valor introducido en ese `TextBox`. Si pongo el `Index de las propiedades del TextBox` en 0 (cero), no puedo añadir más campos. Si lo dejo en 0 (cero) al `index` no puedo añadir `.Text` por ende no puedo guardar el valor.
¿Cómo puedo solucionar ese error? Si necesitan más código se los añado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al usar un indice en controles en VB6, el control (en este caso el textbox), ya no es mas un *control* por si mismo, si no que es un array de controles.

Por lo tanto, `txtAddPrefijo`, es un array, y tenes que tratarlo de la misma forma que hiciste al agregarlo al form, como un array.

Para accederlo a la propiedad texto de cualquiera de ellos, tenes que hacer

```
txtAddPrefijo(X).text
```

Donde X es el indice del array de controles al cual queres acceder.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Pero, en el caso de los `ComboBox`, ¿Cómo sería?

Comment: Igual, es un array de controles, tenes que acceder al control que queres por indice. Es como un array cualquiera. @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: No tengo ni idea, he probado con casi la mayoría de los semejantes que se ven pero en todos da error

Comment: Esa es una pregunta totalmente diferente. Limpiemos esto y aclara que queres hacer con tu combo. Deja esta pregunta como estaba...